# Is it possible to create unzoom element in Raphael?

Tags: javascript, overlay, raphael, zooming

I have a Raphael paper works like google map.

There is a main content just like a map, and many overlay attach on top of it, just like those pin and markers on google map.

So when I zooming, I want the main content to be zoomed, and those overlay need move to the correct position but stay the orignal size. 
(For example, in google map, when I zoom a city, those overlay will always attach to the correct address with same size on screen).

I am currently create thousands of papers, and keep maintain their position manually when zooming happen. but this cause lots of work.
So I am interesting to know if it is possible to draw everything in a single paper. and just do some magic to stop those element be resized when zoom happend.
Something like:

```
    paper.rect(0, 0, 10, 10).attr({resize: false})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need two papers. Put one on top of the other. When zooming the bottom paper, use `setViewBox`. On the top paper, recalculate the positions and translate (`.transform('T...)`) each element.

Comment: I am hoping can avoid calculate positions, because I also deal with lots of drag and move. Is there any way can let the paper it self to handle positions?

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. Even if you set resize:false magically, you'll need to move each marker to a new position.

I can give you a function which I use by myself:

```
markAdjustPosition : function(mark){
        var w = mark.data('width');
        var h = mark.data('height');
        var dx = w/2 - w/(2*_data.scale);
        var dy = h - h/_data.scale;
        mark.attr({width: w/(_data.scale), height: h/(_data.scale)}).transform('t'+dx+','+dy);
},
```

This function will reposition markers considering that marker's target point is on middle of bottom edge (like markers in Google Maps).

**mark** wich you pass to this function is Raphael's Element. You have to add correct default width/height to it in the beginning:

```
Mark.data("width") = 12;
Mark.data("height") = 24;
```

**_data** is my global object for all data in the plugin and **_data.scale** is currect scale (which you'll need to calculate on each zoom level).